# How do you append on array to another?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, append

I'm writing a function to check for multiple file extensions in a folder, and then return the matching file names, but I am having a problem returning the results.

The function 'works', but obviously every time it loops, it reallocates the results of `Directory.GetFiles()` to `Files`, as opposed to appending them. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

And in case anyone wishes to know, I'm doing this because, as far as I can tell, there is no built in way of searcing for multiple patterns with `Directory.GetFiles()`. If this is wrong, please correct me. Thanks.

```
Private Function GetFiles(Path As String, SearchPattern As String)

    Dim SearchPatterns() As String = SearchPattern.Split("|") ' The patterns to search
    Dim Files() As String = Nothing ' The files to return to the user

    For Each Pattern In SearchPatterns

        Files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, Pattern)
        Array.Sort(Files)

    Next

    Return Files

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`List(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class and [`List(Of T).AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead:

```
Private Function GetFiles(Path As String, SearchPattern As String)

    Dim SearchPatterns() As String = SearchPattern.Split("|") ' The patterns to search
    Dim Files As New List(Of String)

    For Each Pattern In SearchPatterns
        Files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(Path, Pattern))
    Next

    Return Files.OrderBy((Function(f) f)).ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: Also, I would recomment sorting only once, after the `For Each` loop. Array.Sort doesn't work on List :)

Comment: @Thorarin Well spotted! Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you muchly, that appears to be doing the job :)